# Overflowing drop down button in a tableview cell: can I make it clickable?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am currently working on a project where I am placing a drop down button inside a tableview cell. The "drop down part" overflows the bottom of the cell and goes into the cell below. Right now I am are not able to click the overflowing part. Are there a way to make this part clickable? You can find a part of my code in the link below

https://github.com/Rawchris/Drop-down-overflow

To spell it out, I would like to be able to click Option 3 and 4 in the project above. Please tell me if you want me to explain my question further.

Comment: please consider this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide reproducable copyable code, because this is not a "we write code for you for free"-platform but a "we help you with your provided code "-platform

Comment: @emrcftci Hi again! Okay, I understand what you are saying. I am still not quite sure how I should ask this question properly though, maybe you can give me an idea on how this question should be expressed?

Comment: first, you should try yourself and after if you will face some issue google it then if you couldn't find any answer re-google it with different keywords. If you still can't find an answer you should ask it in here with some code and explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the question is: you've got a button that goes outside of its superview and therefore cannot be clicked? Yes, you can make the part outside the superview clickable; you'd need to perform "hit-test munging", overriding `hitTest(_:with:)` so that the button can be the hit-test view even when part of it is outside its superview. You would need this code (or similar) in the button's superview:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with e: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if let result = super.hitTest(point, with:e) {
        return result
    }
    for sub in self.subviews.reversed() {
        let pt = self.convert(point, to:sub)
        if let result = sub.hitTest(pt, with:e) {
            return result
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Code was taken directly from my book so it was just a matter of copy and paste. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/a28913fda8a327c76637edac57a3b5b7b3d4d187/bk2ch05p210hitTesting/ch18p551hitTesting/ViewController.swift