# Swift: dropdown overflow disappears when scrolling down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drop-down-menu, overflow

I am working on this project where I am using drop down menus in tableView cells. I am using the following code to make the drop down part overflow the tableView cells bottoms

```
cell.clipsToBounds=false
cell.contentView.clipsToBounds=false
```

Everything works fine, but when I scroll down the tableView till the drop down part is not visible anymore, the overflow stops working. You can see the problem in action in the project below

https://github.com/Rawchris/Drop-down-overflow2

In the project I have put drop down buttons in every cell, but it is fine if it is just the first one that is working. I hope you are able to help. Please tell me if you need anymore information.

Comment: button = DropDownBtn.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        button.setTitle("Button1", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        //Add Button to the View Controller
        self.addSubview(button)


you are adding subview on every cell reload, that's why your view is adding repeatedly one over other,you have to make sure that you add your only once in your view.

Comment: @Arun Hmm, the fact that there is a drop down button in every cell is not the problem, I actually did it on purpose. The main problem is that when I click the button and scroll down, the overflow stops working

Comment: thats what i want to tell you that , you are adding same button continuously on same position thats why it is not tappable, and your dropdown list is cropping because on scroll you next cell presents above previous cell.

Comment: @Arun Ah, okay, so how do I fix this and still keeping the drop down, at least in the first one?

Comment: you shoud add the dropdown in tableview , or you can increase the height of cell, and dont know how it will perform but first of all mark button with tag, and add check before adding in subview that if this cell contain view of  this tag then dont add.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that *"overflow stops working"* ... the problem is that table view cells are not drawn in order.

Taking the answer from your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61252794/6257435

I shortened the cell heights to make it easier to see.

In this image:

[image]

I scrolled up and down a few times before tapping the "Row 8" button. As you can see, your gray "drop down" menu is hidden behind rows 9 and 10.

Using `Debug View Hierarchy` you can see exactly what's going on:

[image]

You *could* get around this by using a closure or delegate protocol to tell your tableViewController to bring that cell to the front when the menu is opened, but... you may still run into issues when scrolling while a "drop down" is showing. You'll also hit problems when the "drop down" is showing for multiple rows at the same time.

In general, it's not a good idea to draw outside the bounds of other views. Many issues can arise. Also - of course, this may be considered just personal opinion - the whole "drop down selection list" feels very out-of-place on a phone or tablet. It makes for a rather clunky / awkward user experience. If I were you, I'd re-think my approach.

Comment: Ah, okay, I understand what you are saying. Maybe we could make a solution, where the dropdown will dismiss when you start scrolling? You could perhaps make a solution to how to "using a closure or delegate protocol to tell your tableViewController to bring that cell to the front when the menu is opened"? And I know it looks kind of weird, but this is just a prototype; I promise you that it makes sense in the real product ;). I that one it is also only the first cell which got a drop down

Comment: @Chris - I can give you a couple more tips tomorrow, but another issue you have likely noticed: you cannot tap on the "drop down" list of items. That's because (again, not a great idea) it extends outside the bounds of its superview. Also, if you tap on a drop-down item that is covering the button in the row below, you actually tap on that button. You *can* get around that using hit-testing... but you're really opening yourself up to additional complications....

Comment: @Chris - Have you considered using drill-down to another table view? Or using a "popover" presentation for the selection list?

Comment: It sounds nice with the tips! I have acceally figured out how to make the drop down list tappable (this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078887/overflowing-drop-down-button-in-a-tableview-cell-can-i-make-it-clickable), so that is only a problem when the list disappears behind the other cells. And again, in my real project it will only be the first cell which have a drop down button, so the fact that you can tap the button in the cell below through the drop down list should not be a problem

Comment: And yes, I have considered other options, but I am sp close to make this work, I think I only need to fix this problem to be done