# swift: button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false stops working when scrolling tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, scroll

I am using a tableview where the first cell contains two buttons. When the first button is activated, the second should be disabled (you should not be able to press it). It all works fine until I start scrolling down the tableview. If I scroll down as far as possible while still being able to see the buttons in first cell, and I activate the first button, I am still able to press the other one. Other things also stops working, but I guess that it is cause by the same thing. Do you have any idea on what happens? See the gif below to see what is going on

[image]

I have uploaded the source code on this link, if you need it

https://github.com/Rawchris/scroll-down

I hope you can help :)

Comment: I believe this happens because you are using reusable cells. 

You always have to set your button state for every cell. The away to do that would be to inform the array feeding the tableview with the correct status for each button which you can do with a delegate from the cell to the tableview. 

Advice: I would not insert so much logic inside TableViewCell.

Comment: try adding 'cell.button.isUserInteractionEnabled = cell.newStatus` in cellForItemAt

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha Okay, and how would I activate and deactivate it via the button?

Comment: @Chris - you're doing a couple things wrong. Cells are ***reused*** - your code is calling `cell.setTableViewCell()` in `cellForRowAt`, which means it gets called every time a cell is reused. In your cell code for `setTableViewCell()`, you are adding a button - that means you are adding ***another*** button every time the cell is reused. You need to add the button once - usually in the cell class's `init`, and then set its properties in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: @DonMag Ah, okay, nice. Maybe you post a solution where I can see how it should be done?

Comment: @Chris - if you tap "Button" in the second row, to disable the "Button1" drop-down, do you want it to ***remain*** disabled when you scroll down so second row is off-screen, and then scroll back up to reveal second row again? Or should it automatically become re-enabled?

Comment: @DonMag I think I want it to remain disabled when it goes off-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table view cells are reused - which means a couple things:

- in general (particularly for your case) you should only add UI elements when you initialize the cell. Otherwise, new ones get added over and over and over.
- you need to maintain "row" information, usually in your data source. In this example, you want at least an array of Bool values indicating whether the button in the row should be enabled or not when the cell is reused.

Change your View Controller class to this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // this would be replaced with your real data
    // test with 20 rows
    // start with all rows having button enabled
    var buttonStatus: [Bool] = Array(repeating: true, count: 20)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Configure the button
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat(200)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return buttonStatus.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

        cell.setButtonEnabled(buttonStatus[indexPath.row], with: "Row \(indexPath.row)")

        cell.callback = { b in
            // update data source with enabled state of button
            self.buttonStatus[indexPath.row] = b
        }

        return cell

    }
}
```

and change your cell class to this:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var callback: ((Bool) -> ())?

    var button = DropDownBtn()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        button = DropDownBtn.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        button.setTitle("Button1", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        //Add Button to the View Controller
        self.addSubview(button)

        //button Constraints
        button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

        //Set the drop down menu's options
        button.dropView.dropDownOptions = ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4"]

        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.contentView.clipsToBounds=false

    }

    func setButtonEnabled(_ b: Bool, with title: String) {
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = b
        // update the UI - green enabled, red disabled
        button.backgroundColor = b ? UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.6, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0) : .red
        // update the title so we can see what row we're on
        button.setTitle(title, for: [])
    }

    @IBAction func deactivate(_ sender: Any) {
        // toggle the enabled property of "button"
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = !button.isUserInteractionEnabled
        // tell the controller the status changed
        callback?(button.isUserInteractionEnabled)
        // update the UI - green enabled, red disabled
        button.backgroundColor = button.isUserInteractionEnabled ? UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.6, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0) : .red
    }

}
```

This will demonstrate using an array to track the Bool enabled state for the dropDown button in each row. It also changes the button's background color to Green when enabled, Red when disabled. And, it sets the Title of the dropDown button to make it easy to see which rows you're looking at when you scroll up and down.

[image]

Comment: Waow, thank you so much. It works! Maybe you are also able to answer why the drop down part gets covered when scrolling down? I have made an other question if you are able to answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61170547/swift-dropdown-overflow-disappears-when-scrolling-down

Comment: @Chris - I answered at your other question.

Comment: Damn, you are amazing!!